# Определить system power state

Tags: windows

Имеется ПК под управлением Windows 8+. Как известно, на кнопку "Завершение работы" можно назначить множество состояний. Необходимо узнать в какое состояние отправилась система. Состояния могут быть следующими:

- S3 (sleep)
- S3 (hybrid sleep)
- S4 (hibernation)
- S4 (hybrid shutdown state)
- S5 (off)

Можно ли как-то узнать в каком состоянии пребывала система? Может быть это можно как-то отловить до ухода в определенное состояние или после (когда система просыпается). Я обыскался, но ничего по этому поводу не нашел... Есть функции [Power Management Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), но они не решают данную проблему.

Будьте добры, дайте направление.

P.S. Поясню, что в мою задачу не входит считывание текущей настройки, указанной для "Завершения работы". Мне необходимо определить пост-эффект, когда система уже отправилась в какое-либо состояние. Если раскрывать проблему совсем, то вот её суть. Я вызываю hybrid shutdown state для удаленного компьютера (через `shutdown.exe /s /hybrid /m compname`). Но по непонятным причинам он не переходит в S4 (hybrid shutdown state). Предположительно, система отправляется в классический S5, но хотелось бы знать наверняка.
Если подобные вопросы тут не решаются, то может быть кто-то в курсе, где их можно обсудить.
И я был бы крайне благодарен за готовое решение (какую-нибудь утилитку или логгер), но похоже, что таковых не существует.